# SQL Query One to many no match

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables T1.T1badge in Table1 may match T2.OldBadge or T2.New_Badge from Table2 or T1.T1badge may not match either field in T2 need the ones that don't match either Field in Table2.

This is what i have it runs but doesn't work provide the null value records.

```
SELECT T1.T1USERID, T1.T1USER, T1.T1badge, T2.CC INTO NewTable_NoCC
FROM T1, T2
WHERE (((T2.[NEW_ID])=[T1].[T1badge])) OR (((T2.OldBadge)=[T1].[T1badge]))
AND (T2.CC IS NULL);
```

Comment: I should state i am using SQL in Access

Comment: Look up how left/right joins work.  That is a method of pulling all records from one side, even if they don't match.

Comment: Is hard to guess what is your desire result.

Comment: Your table names are T1 and T2?   Even if you are just experimenting and testing, those are horrible names.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

First remove the into to see if this return the data you want.

THEN use left join and check for parenthesis. Is hard to test access query.

```
SELECT T1.T1USERID, T1.T1USER, T1.T1badge, T2.CC 
FROM T1
LEFT JOIN T2
       ON (((T2.[NEW_ID])=[T1].[T1badge])) 
           OR (((T2.OldBadge)=[T1].[T1badge]))
WHERE (T2.CC IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  T1.T1USERID, T1.T1USER, T1.T1badge, T2.CC
INTO    NewTable_NoCC
FROM    T1 
        LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.T1BADGE IN (T2.NEW_ID, T2.OLDBADGE)
WHERE   T2.CC IS NULL
```

Left Join is the key to this query.

Comment: Thanks for the help I did figure out the Left Join was the key.